# Compare multiple columns for each row

Tags: linux, bash, awk, gawk

Using a csv file, i will like to compare multiple columns to check if all values are the same or not.

First row are the headers
First column is the label 
The constant values should be from column 2 to the end ( can be 100 columns ) for the example i put only 8 columns.

The purpose is to check that all values are the same. and when it is not, report

input file

```
Number,V2 1563,V03-1555,V4 - 294,V-05 1580,V6-1561,V7-1562,V05-1601,V9-1587
Code,4.1.06,4.1.03,4.1.06,4.1.06,4.1.06,4.1.06,4.1.06,4.1.06
Host Id,b90c27,b90c13,3.30E+65,b90c46,b90c21,b90c1f,b88a63,b90c49
SR,SR_2_MS,SR_2_MS,SR_4_MS,SR_2_MS,SR_2_MS,SR_2_MS,SR_2_MS,SR_2_MS
```

output desired

```
Bad code in V03-1555
Bad SR in V4 - 294
```

Appreciate your support

Comment: why not Host Id values not reported?

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Edit your Q to show sample inputs/outputs and your best attempt at code. Sorry, but requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and free code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

I improvised little bit.  How do we know which values are correct, which are not?  Popular vote, counts the occurrences and assumes majority is right.  As a side benefit, if all values are different as in your "Host Id" row, nothing is reported

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1 {split($0,h); next} 
                 {delete r; 
                  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {r[$i]++; idx[$i]=i}
                  max=0;
                  for(k in r) if(max<r[k]) max=r[k];
                  if(length(r)>1) 
                    for(k in r) 
                      if(r[k]!=max) 
                        print "Bad " $1 " in " h[idx[k]] " -> " k}' file
```

returns

```
Bad Code in V03-1555 -> 4.1.03
Bad SR in V4 - 294 -> SR_4_MS
```

you can remove the values printed, which I put for verification.

Comment: karakfa, awesome code :) that is exactly what I was looking for, appreciate your help.  The logic used in the code "assumes majority is right. As a side benefit, if all values are different as in your "Host Id" row, nothing is reported" is what i was looking for.. That is the reason why "why not Host Id values not reported?" again thanks